# GestureListener after change orientation. Android. Xamarin. c#

Tags: c#, android, video, xamarin, touch

I am building an application that uses camera to take pictures and record video. I implement my activity from `GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener`and `Wiew.IOnTouchListener` to detect the screen taps.

```
 public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
        if (isLongClick && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            StopMediaRecorderRecord();
            ReleaseMediaRecorder();
            AddFirstFrameToLayout(currentVideoPath);
            OpenCamera();
            canTakePhoto = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        isLongClick = false;
        return true;
    }
    public bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        canTakePhoto = false;
        mCamera.StopPreview();
        mCamera.Release();

        currentVideoPath = SetVideoSettings();

        recorder.Start();
        isLongClick = true;

    }

    public bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
    }

    public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        TakePictureByCamera();
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

In application I add `ScrollView` in which I put `LinearLayoutand` when I take photo/video, I dynamically create `RelativeLayout`, in which I put `ImageView` with this photo/video and add `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` (which in `ScrollView`).

When I do a longpress on screen, I start recording a video, and when I tapUp, the video recording stopped. It works funny if I don't change screen orientation. But when I start record video by doing longPress and then rotate my phone, it doesn't respond on tapUp and continues record video.

Detailed code:

```
[Activity(Label = "App2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", ConfigurationChanges = (ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize))]

public class MainActivity : Activity, ISurfaceHolderCallback, Android.Hardware.Camera.IPictureCallback, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private SurfaceView sv;
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private bool canTakePhoto = true;
    private bool isLongClick;

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    private LinearLayout linearlayout;
    private ISurfaceHolder sHolder;
    private Android.Hardware.Camera mCamera;
    private Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;

    private string pathToWrite = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    private string currentVideoPath;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);

        screenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
        screenHeight = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;

        sv = (SurfaceView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.surfaceView1);
        sHolder = sv.Holder;
        sHolder.AddCallback(this);
        sHolder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);

        LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mylinearlayout);
        linearlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.filesScrollerLayout);
        linearlayout.SetOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        var width = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
        var height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
    }

    public static string GetDateString()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
    }

    private string SetVideoSettings()
    {
        string videoPath = pathToWrite + "/" + GetDateString() + ".mp4";
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
        recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Camcorder);
        recorder.SetProfile(CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.High));
        recorder.SetOutputFile(videoPath);
        recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(sHolder.Surface);
        recorder.Prepare();

        return videoPath;
    }

    private void SetCameraResolution()
    {
        IList<Android.Hardware.Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.SupportedPictureSizes;
        parameters.SetPictureSize(sizes[0].Width, sizes[0].Height);
    }
    private void SetCameraSettings()
    {
        parameters = mCamera.GetParameters();
        parameters.SetRotation(90);
        SetCameraResolution();
        mCamera.SetParameters(parameters);
    }

    private void OpenCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            mCamera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();
            mCamera.SetPreviewDisplay(sHolder);
            SetCameraSettings();
            mCamera.StartPreview();

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            if (mCamera != null)
            {
                ReleaseCamera();
            }

        }
    }

    private void TakePictureByCamera()
    {
        if (canTakePhoto)
        {
            mCamera.AutoFocus(null);
            mCamera.TakePicture(null, null, this);
            canTakePhoto = false;
        }
    }

    private View CreateRelativeLayout()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null, false);
    }

    private ImageView CreateImageViewFromRelativeLayout(View layout)
    {
        return (ImageView)layout.FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView);
    }

    private Button CreateButtonFromRelativeLayout(View layout, string videoPath)
    {
        Button button = (Button)layout.FindViewById(Resource.Id.button);
        SetButtonEvent(button, videoPath);
        return button;
    }

    private void SetButtonEvent(Button button, string videoPath)
    {
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(PlayerActivity));
            activity2.PutExtra("MyData", videoPath);
            StartActivity(activity2);
        };
    }

    private void AddBitmapToLayout(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        linearlayout.AddView(iv);
    }

    private void AddFirstFrameToLayout(string videoPath)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever metadata = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metadata.SetDataSource(videoPath);
        Bitmap firstFrame = metadata.FrameAtTime;

        View relativeLayout = CreateRelativeLayout();
        ImageView newImage = CreateImageViewFromRelativeLayout(relativeLayout);
        Button newButton = CreateButtonFromRelativeLayout(relativeLayout, videoPath);

        newImage.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        newImage.SetImageBitmap(firstFrame);
        linearlayout.AddView(relativeLayout);
    }

    private void StopCameraPreview()
    { 
        mCamera.StopPreview();
    }

    private void StopMediaRecorderRecord()
    {
        recorder.Stop();
    }

    private void ReleaseMediaRecorder()
    {
        recorder.Release();
        recorder = null;
    }

    private void ReleaseCamera()
    {
        mCamera.Release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
    {

    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        OpenCamera();
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (recorder == null)
        {
            StopCameraPreview();
            ReleaseCamera();
        }
        else
        {
            StopMediaRecorderRecord();                
            ReleaseMediaRecorder();
        }

    }

    private Bitmap DecodeCameraPhotoToBitmap(byte[] data)
    {
        return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    private Bitmap CreateScaledBitmapFromPhoto(Bitmap bmp, int width, int height)
    {
        return Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
    }

    private void BitmapRecycle(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        bmp.Recycle();
        bmp = null;
    }

    private void WorkingWithBitmap(byte[] data)
    {
        Bitmap cameraBitmap = DecodeCameraPhotoToBitmap(data);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = CreateScaledBitmapFromPhoto(cameraBitmap, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        AddBitmapToLayout(scaledBitmap);
        BitmapRecycle(cameraBitmap);
    }

    void Android.Hardware.Camera.IPictureCallback.OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        SavePictureTask task = new SavePictureTask(data);
        task.Execute();

        WorkingWithBitmap(data);          

        mCamera.StartPreview();
        canTakePhoto = true;
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
        if (isLongClick && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            StopMediaRecorderRecord();
            ReleaseMediaRecorder();
            AddFirstFrameToLayout(currentVideoPath);
            OpenCamera();
            canTakePhoto = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        isLongClick = false;
        return true;
    }
    public bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        canTakePhoto = false;
        mCamera.StopPreview();
        mCamera.Release();

        currentVideoPath = SetVideoSettings();

        recorder.Start();
        isLongClick = true;

    }

    public bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
    }

    public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        TakePictureByCamera();
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
       return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }

}
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try always returning true from `OnTouch` method

Comment: @Giorgi Not working:(

Comment: Did you keep gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e) inside OnTouch or did you delete it?

Comment: @Giorgi I tried to keep and delete. It doesn't work in any case.

Comment: Can you show us how/where you set up the listeners?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe In application I add  `ScrollView` in which I put `LinearLayout`and when I take photo/video, I dynamically create  `RelativeLayout`, in which I put  `ImageView` with this photo/video and add  `RelativeLayout` to  `LinearLayout` (which in  `ScrollView`). So I set `SetOnTouchListener` for Main Layout in `protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` and for `ImageView` [link](http://pastebin.com/q3wcBpzT)

Comment: Update your question, and show us the code in detail.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe I updated my question.